# How to realize screens / views with JavaScript / Jquery easily?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsrender

I'm sure I'm missing something pretty basic, but I have just started to get myself up to speed on jQuery and Javascript programming. Previously I was doing server side programming with PHP.
I'm now in the middle of creating a prototype for HTML5 webapp, where I would like to have different screens. Now with PHP that was pretty easy, I could just used server side templates like Smarty and be done with it.

However to make my app more webapp like, I would like to dynamically change between screens without having to reload the window.

I have looked into several options that might be anwsers to my question, but I'm not sure whether I'm on the right track.

I have checked for example JsRender, JsViews or even the pure jquery load command.
But what I'm not sure is whether these things would allow me to have something like this:

HEADER_PART
MAIN_CONTENT
FOOTER_PART (also contains links to common JS files that I use)

I would like to dynamically update the MAIN_CONTENT part. Currently my application is only one page, and all my custom logic that belongs to that page is in one JS file. In this JS file, I use a simple $(function() { ... to load my page, so whenever it gets loaded, parts of my page get updated asyncronously. This is fine, since all my blocks in this certain page would have to be loaded when that one page gets loaded.

But what if I have a link, like main.html#otherscreen, and when I click that screen, I would like to change my MAIN_CONTENT and also run another page load specific JS that handles blocks on that other screen, not the first page?

I know I could still use probably server side templating and load my pages using AJAX requrests, but again, not sure whether that is the right approach.

Could you please enlighten me? :)

Thanks & best regards,
Bence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/). Using this function you can dynamically load content into a div on the page, which is what I think you want to do. Just find the `div` on the page you want to load content into and call

```
$('#mydiv').load(url, data, function(response){
    //do something once it's done.
});
```

---

**Per your comments...**

This is actually very easy. `.load()` should replace the content in the div (I think. If not, just call `.empty()` first). Of course you could get fancy and add effects, like

```
function changePages(url) {
    $('#mydiv').fadeOut('fast', function() { 
        $(this).load(url, function(response){
            $('#mydiv').fadeIn('fast');
        });
    });
}
```

To handle things like the hash in the URL, in your click event you have to make sure you first call `e.preventDefault()`:

```
$('#mylink').click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); //e is a jquery event object
    var link = $(this);
    var hash = link.attr('href'); // get the hashtag if the href is '#something'
    changePages(someUrl + hash);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That's also something I have looked into but I'm still missing some pieces of the puzzle, namely how to implement the transition between the pages and how to handle the different pages differently, only based on the hash value in the URL (like I would have two pages: main.html#mainpage and main.html#otherpage. I would like to have only one html page and it would load different pages dynamically, and it would handle the blocks belonging to each page separately.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This now makes sense! My last question is whether you would think that this approach is a valid one? (I mean, that I implement a multipage (multiscreen) webapp with this approach). SEO is not an issue, since the application will not be running on an openly accessible URL. Question is whether this approach is good for performance or for other reasons.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with this way. here's a pretty solid full demo of how to do this technique: http://css-tricks.com/dynamic-page-replacing-content/

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic loading of data into the page without changing your header and footer you should use jQuery's AJAX function. It allows you to post requests to the server and receive data back without reloading the page. A simple example would be something like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <!-- Assuming jQuery is already referenced -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('span.buttonish').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    // The URL can be a file or a PHP script of your choosing
                    // it can also be pure HTML without the <html> tags as they
                    // are already in your file
                    url: 'path/to/the/file/that/return/data',
                    success: function(receivedData) {
                        // The received data is the content of the file or the return
                        // data of the script and you can use it as you would with any data
                        $('#content').html(receivedData);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
        <!-- Something -->
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <span class="buttonish">Click me to change the text... </span>
        </div>
        </div id="footer">
        <!-- Something -->
        </div>
    </body>
<html>
```